# Select multiple columns but group by only 1 column

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, max

I have a comment table

| comment_id | when_added |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 02/23/2022 |
| 21 | 02/23/2022 |
| 10 | 02/24/2022 |

I needed to get the count, comment_id, and the latest when_added

| comment_id | when_added | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 02/24/2022 | 2 |
| 21 | 02/23/2022 | 1 |

I tried this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, comment_id, when_added 
FROM comment 
GROUP BY comment_id, when_added 
ORDER BY when_added DESC;
```

Is there a way to group by only using comment_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should group only by `comment_id` and get the last `when_added` for each `comment_id` with `MAX()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT comment_id, 
       MAX(when_added) last_when_added, 
       COUNT(*) count
FROM comment 
GROUP BY comment_id 
ORDER BY last_when_added DESC;
```